# Trigger to update a linked server table when specific values are entered

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-update, linked-server

I'm synchronizing two separate database applications. The databases are linked servers. One is a CRM and one is an ERP. When the user enters one of three code strings in the quates table status column of the CRM, the project table status of the ERP needs to be updated when one of three text strings.

```
CN=Converted
WO=Working
PN=Pending
```

CRM Quotes Table

```
CompanyID QuoteID Status
```

User enters (1 of three codes)

```
CN
WO
PN
```

ERP Project Table

```
CompanyID ProjectID Status
```

Status updated to (1 of three strings)

```
Converted
Working
Pending
```

It seems like it would be something like

```
UPDATE ERP.dbo.Projects
SET ERP.dbo.Projects.Status = 'Converted'
FROM Inserted.CRM.Projects
WHERE Inserted.CRM.Projects Status = 'CN'
INNER JOIN ERP.dbo.Project.ProjectID = CRM.dbo.Quotes.QuoteID

UPDATE ERP.dbo.Projects
SET ERP.dbo.Projects.Status = 'Working'
FROM Inserted.CRM.Projects
WHERE Inserted.CRM.Projects Status = 'WO'
INNER JOIN ERP.dbo.Project.ProjectID = CRM.dbo.Quotes.QuoteID

UPDATE ERP.dbo.Projects
SET ERP.dbo.Projects.Status = 'Pending'
FROM Inserted.CRM.Projects
WHERE Inserted.CRM.Projects Status = PN
INNER JOIN ERP.dbo.Project.ProjectID = CRM.dbo.Quotes.QuoteID
```

Would it be best to use a case or if statement or use 3 separate triggers for each code?

Database: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Definitely don't use 3 separate triggers. That would be totally crazy. I would make this a single update statement with a case expression instead of 3 separate update statements. And definitely NOT an IF statement, that just doesn't make sense in this context at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a lot of detail here but you have some logical flaws in your updates as posted. I suspect you want something more like this.

```
UPDATE p
SET Status = 
    case i.Status when 'CN' then'Converted'
        when 'WO' then 'Working'
        where 'PN' then 'Pending'
    end
from inserted i
INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.Projects p on p.ProjectID = i.QuoteID
```